# "nocumentare" nella lingua italiana, nascita e morte

Tags: word-usage, verbs, phrase-request, resources

È leggendo [*Adam Smith, John Nash, il prezzo dell’anarchia e la decadenza della società moderna*](http://ithaca.unisalento.it/nr-02_12_13/bilo.pdf) di Vittorio Bilò che (re)incontro con piacere la parola [nocumento](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nocumento/), parola già incontrata nelle [opere pirandelliane](https://www.google.de/search?q=nocumento%20pirandello&oq=nocumento%20pirandello&aqs=chrome..69i57.5520j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=nocumento%20pirandello&tbm=bks). Mi capitò una volta, ai tempi del liceo scientifico, di usare il verbo “nocumentare” durante una prova orale di filosofia e la mia prof non disse niente a riguardo, se corretto o meno era quel verbo in italiano, se esisteva più che altro. La prof mi capì insomma, saranno stati i suoi studi oltre di filosofia anche di lettere classiche, *ergo* vedeva “lecito” l’uso del verbo nocumentare dal “[nocumentum](http://www.dizionario-latino.com/dizionario-latino-italiano.php?parola=nocumentum)” latino, che non le diedero motivo di correggermi. Ma è un verbo usato in italiano? E in latino? Esistono ovvero? Treccani ed altri non danno alcun risultato per il verbo, i dizionari latini *idem*, ma se cerco con Google compare una lista di [scritti in latino](https://www.google.de/search?q=nocumento%20significato&oq=nocume&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.4193j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=nocumentare) (Savanarola è l’unico che mi salta all’occhio) e [uno in italiano](https://www.google.de/search?q=nocumento+pirandello&oq=nocumento+pirandello&aqs=chrome..69i57.5520j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=nocumentare) (in fondo ovvero [CLIC](https://books.google.de/books?id=fnQmAQAAIAAJ&q=nocumentare&dq=nocumentare&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuwJWIg9_TAhUBWxoKHRnyB8kQ6AEIXDAI)). Allora esiste in italiano? Se sì, perché nessun dizionario lo riporta anche sotto la voce **rar**(*issimissimo*), *idem* dicasi per il latino? Ammetto che la community è esclusivamente per l’italiano, quindi se non ho risposta, diversamente non in latino spero LOL, per l’uso in quella lingua morta mi accontento lo stesso. Inoltre, può questo verbo essere stato  usato solo in un intorno degli inizi del ’900? Qualcuno ha grafici o dati o altre fonti d’uso in relazione a questo verbo? (Strano che [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nocumentare&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) non dia risultati, ammesso lo usi correttamente mi domando ”cosa *caspiterina* scansiona se in Google Books esiste lo scritto?”)

Comment: Credo proprio che non esista, e che il verbo da usare invece sia [*nuocere*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nuocere/). Personalmente non avrei mai capito *nocumentare* (probabilmente avrei capito *nocumento* ma non senza un bel po' di perplessità).

Comment: *n(u)ocere, recar(e) danno, essere causa di danno, ledere, compromettere*... sono tutti sinonimi tra loro. *nocumentare* è stato usato, almeno una volta date le fonti, il suo uso è errato? Non penso, o credo di no. Il suo uso allora sarebbbe arcaico? Sicuro, date le fonti sempre! Ha un qualche legame con il l`ipotetico verbo latino "nocumentare"? Non so, chiedo! Si sa che il sinonimo di *nocumento* é *nocimento* (e questo deriva piú direttamente da *n(u)ocere*, che deriva dal latino *nocere*).

Comment: Che sia un errore di battitura quello presente in "La Rassegna nazionale"? Forse si, vai a vedere come scrivevano o stampavano allora, e chiedo anche, perplesso sono tuttavia poiché *nocimento* con *n(u)ocere*, per analogia tra nome e verbo, ci sta e difficil mi vien da pensar che non possa dirsi lo stesso per *nocumento* e *nocumentare*.

Comment: Che sia comparso e scomparso fa pensare, pensare se magari era nato con la "u" trasformatasi in "i", in un arco di tempo brevissimo!? Forse si, e in relazione alla domanda difficile mi vien da capire come secondo google *nocumento* ha una "difusione" maggiore di *nocimento*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nocimento%2Cnocumento&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnocimento%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnocumento%3B%2Cc0 LOL -_- anche se si usa *n(u)ocere*

Comment: Chiedo umilmente insomma, ma non un questo verbo piuttosto che quello "da usare invece" (Preferivo Treccani e non chiedere). Pardon per la mia durezza nel commento, non ci fare caso ergo a questa, sará l´orario e la stanchezza! :) ;) :D :P E pardon anche se devi leggere tanti commenti, ma il limite di caratteri non mi ha mai spinto ad avere migliori capacitá di sintesi, sará un modo, qualora ci si arriva, per favorire l´uso della chat....

Comment: (esiste anche *nuocimento* creando ad hoc una corrispondenza perfetta con il verbo *n(u)ocere*, mi suonava strano che non potesse esistere per me Siciliano amante della vocale "u")

Comment: Che vuol dire “diversamente non in latino spero LOL”?

Comment: Mi sono permesso di aggiungere l'autore dell'articolo che citi, perché è lui che ha scelto di usare quella parola, non Adam Smith né Nash. :-)

Comment: Infine: non ragionare sempre in termini di “corretto o no”. Come già è venuto fuori qui in altre circostanze, l'italiano (come tutte le lingue naturali) non è un sistema chiuso, formalizzato, con un insieme di vocaboli e regole fisso. Ogni parlante, nei limiti di una certa coerenza (e del fatto di farsi capire) ha una sua libertà di “forzare” l'italiano, coniare parole “nuove” con radici e suffissi preesistenti etc. Se esagera non lo capiranno, se quella parola “mancava” cominceranno a usarla in molti e così via.

Comment: Probabilmente la comunità dei parlanti non ha quasi mai, per così dire, sentito il bisogno di “nocumentare” in presenza dei già attestati “nuocere” e relativi sinonimi, ma se ti piace usalo finché vuoi. Se pensi che l'italiano sia una lingua rigida e che ogni parola e regola abbiano bisogno di un'attestazione precedente, apri una qualsiasi pagina di Gadda.

Comment: @DaG, Gadda sarebbe http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/carlo-emilio-gadda_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)?

Comment: @mle, non sono sicuro se stai scherzando, ma nel dubbio prendo sul serio la tua domanda: sì, è lui, è uno scrittore che gode di una certa fama.

Comment: perché dovrei scerzare? Non trovo motivo alcuno. Comunque, è un autore da me mai affrontato, mai letto e mai saputo di lui. Al 5o liceo ne abbiamo fatti tanti, Verga, D´Annunzio (questi due iniziati giá al 4o ma solo nelle loro concezioni e poetiche), Pirandello (ricordo ancora le letture quasi noiose, senza sapere a priori cosa fosse il teatro per Pirandello, delle sue opere teatrali e tutte le volte che siamo corsi a Palermo a vederle), Svevo, Saba, Ungaretti, Montale, Quasimodo, ed altri ancora sino ai gg quasi nostri come alcune pagine delle opere di "Aldo Busi",

Comment: metti autori stranieri anche, femminili pure, e non solo letture delle loro concezioni e poetiche ma pagine pagine delle loro opere, metti anche i tantissimi progetti lettura sugli autori siciliani del gruppo Sciascia-Bufalino-Consolo (con qualcosa di Camilleri), da trattare assolutamente, ed altri come Navarro della Miraglia del realismo sicialino con tante loro opere da leggere, ed altri testi di altri progetti lettura che solo al 5o in cui io frequentavo erano cosí tanti e tutti i professori dovevano affrontare gli autori... che capita di non fare Gadda,

Comment: in altre parti non si trattano tanti altri autori sentendo "Verga é poco utile" (ed altri commenti su Ungaretti e Quasimodo) -_- Col tempo provvedo, in primis con la riapertura del Baldi alla voce Gadda sperando non ci dedica una mezza paginetta come è suo solito fare dalla metá libro (per il 5o anno) in poi!

Answer (score 1):

Per quanto la lingua italiana non sia un sistema chiuso ritengo che piegare un sostantivo per farlo diventare verbo sia un po' troppo, per quanto uno voglia essere flessibile sui neologismi. Lo ritengo una bruttura un po' come quando leggo "utilizzazione" al posto di "utilizzo".
*Cagionar nocumento* potrebbe essere una formulazione più "corretta" dal sentore comunque arcaico.